# jQuery hoverIntent - prevent hoverOut while on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some links linked to a hoverIntent event:

```
<div class="hovertrig">Hello</div>
<div class="hovertrig">Hello</div>

<div class="hovercard"></div>
```

Hovering over 'hovertrig' will position 'hovercard' relative to it, but when I mouse over the newly position 'hovercard' div, it fades out. I'd like to prevent the fadeout until they move their mouse pointer outside of the hovercard/triggering div for a second or two.

I'm using http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('[data-shoptip]').hoverIntent(hoverOn, hoverOff);});

function hoverOn(t) {
    $('.hovercard').show();
    $('.hovercard').css('top', $(this).offset().top - 200).css('left', $(this).offset().left + 15);
    console.log(this);
}

function hoverOff(t, event) {
    $('.hovercard').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: $('.hovertrig').hoverIntent(hoverOn, hoverOff);

Comment: How many `hovercard` you have just 1? Can you show the css/layout for that.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?